# Strict aliasing violation

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

Does the following program violate the strict aliasing rule?

```
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    double d = 0.1;

    //std::int64_t n = *reinterpret_cast<std::int64_t*>(&d); // aliasing violation

    //auto n{*reinterpret_cast<std::int64_t*>(&d)}; // aliasing violation

    auto nptr{reinterpret_cast<std::int64_t*>(&d)};
    auto& n{*nptr};

    ++n;
}
```

No warning emitted by VS2015, [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cb070ba530f7471) or [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08ee9b24c38e6333).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does the following program violate the strict aliasing rule?

Yes, it does. You are dereferencing a `double*` (`&d`) using a `std::int64_t*`.

The line that violates strict aliasing rule is:

```
auto& n{*nptr};
```

While processing the line, the compilers don't necessarily know how you set the value of `nptr`. The fact that it is an alias to a `double*` is not obvious while processing that line.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this violates strict aliasing. You are accessing an object `d` of type `double`, though a pointer `nptr` which is not a pointer to `double` or any type related to it.

Just because a compiler does not emit a warning does not mean it isn't a violation. Violations of strict arising are UB (since they're a matter of runtime behavior) and therefore do not require a diagnostic.

Comment: Re " Violations of strict [aliasing] are UB", not at all. Strict aliasing is a gcc notion connected to its optimization. The C++ standard instead has rules about how the results of reinterpretation can be used (or not) in portable ways. In this example that causes formal UB. But the example can be good on a given platform.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: "*The C++ standard instead has rules about how the results of reinterpretation can be used (or not) in portable ways.*" And those rules are generally called the "strict aliasing rules"; the term may come from a GCC option, but the rules themselves do not. So I don't see what your point is. And no, the example is not allowed to be well-defined behavior on any platform. 3.10/10 does not allow you to *ever* access the value of a `double` through the a pointer to `int64_1`.

Comment: The view that C and C++ *can't* do type punning on specific platforms is contrary to reality. So that response is a very good example of what I attempted to point out. Unfortunately that view makes g++ (and clang as a plug-in replacement) less practically useful than it could have been.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: "*The view that C and C++ can't do type punning on specific platforms is contrary to reality.*" That's not the "view" at all. The "view" is that the C++ standard *does not protect* it. If you want to rely on type punning, that's fine; you are simply relying on *undefined behavior*. If you want to do that, that's fine. But you *cannot pretend* the standard does not declare it to be UB.